# How to create a transaction to insert multiple queries

Tags: java, jdbc, vert.x, reactive

I'm trying to create a transaction in Rx vert.x 4.4.4 with Java. I spent a lot of time in it, but I can't get it done.

I'm using JDBCC Client:

```
@Inject
public CompanyRepositoryImpl(final Vertx vertx) {
    pool = JDBCPool.pool(vertx, Config.getInstance().getAuthDbConfig());
}
```

```
private Object createTransaction(List<String> QUERY_TO_EXECUTE) {
    return pool.rxGetConnection().doOnSuccess(conn -> {
        conn.rxBegin().doOnSuccess(tx -> {

            conn.preparedQuery(null)
                .rxExecute(null)
                .flatMap(rows -> {
                    return null;
                    }
                );
            tx.rxCommit();
        });
    });
}
```

The goal is to execute the list of queries that comes from the QUERY_TO_EXECUTE arg , and execute in order, A THEN B THEN C THEN D ...

And if some query fail, complete transaction fail.

I tried a lot of things but none worked for me.

I tried reading Vert.x 4.4.4 doc, but none of that worked for me. Using rxWithTransaction() or rxWithConnection(), please help me.

Comment: What does not work with `io.vertx.reactivex.sqlclient.Pool#rxWithTransaction` ? Can you update the snippet and share the error?